# High memory utilization with DXA 2.0

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 2.0 Java. DXA Web application is deployed on high configuration Linux server (16 GB Ram and 8 core CPU) using Tomcat 8.5.30. We are experiencing high memory utilization with small load on server. It takes all available heap memory and memory utilization does not go down. We have done similar load test with DXA Demo application shipped with DXA installation and got same high memory utilization.

Below are Tomcat Environment settings:

```
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms1024M -Xmx3072M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
```

Comment: Is the high memory utilization causing issues?  Could it be related to caching? What happens if you disable caching?

Comment: @RickPannekoek caching is already disabled.Due to high memory utilization website became very slow once it reached maximum